# Spring boot with Java 8 Intellij project

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-8, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I want to create a Springboot project with java 8 inn Intellij but I couldn't:
when i tried to create the standard way I only find Java 17 and 21 to choose from:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7RMm.png)

After that i created a normal project with Java 21 and then tried to scale the java version down. I reconfigured the pom.xml and i got this error:

```
C:\..\test\src\main\java\com\example\test\HelloController.java:4:47
java: cannot access org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
  bad class file: /C:/Users/../.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.1.3/spring-web-6.1.3.jar!/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.class
    class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


<!--    <properties>-->
<!--        <java.version>1.8</java.version>-->
<!--        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>-->
<!--        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>-->
<!--    </properties>-->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version> <!-- Replace with the latest version -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version> <!-- Replace with the latest version -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version> <!-- Replace with the latest version -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version> <!-- Replace with the latest version compatible with your MySQL version -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version> <!-- Replace with the latest version -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot DevTools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version> <!-- Replace with the latest version -->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version> <!-- Replace with the latest version -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

ps:
I have Java 8
and Maven 3.8.5 installed.

I tried scaling down the java version to 1.8 and added maven compiler 1.8

any idea ? thank you

Comment: you need to make sure all your dependencies have to be compatible with Java 8. Just check about what class the error message talks, check in what dependency that is, and adjust it's version

Comment: @Stultuske exactly, how to accept your answet?

Comment: not, since it's a comment, not an answer.